# How to parse state from one component to another in my example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to create a weather site. One of the features I have is that I currently have a map of Europe (made in SVG). Every country on this map have a country code (e.g. Poland = 'pl') which will be saved in state. 
When this country is clicked, I fill the country on the SVG map with red.

My problem is that I have another component, which should retrieve WOEID id for the country, given the country code '*pl*'.

But I do not know how to get access to the state variable; currentCountryCode, in the other component.

Below I show you my component which has the europe map and the state variables I need to parse further.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../css/index.css";
import FindWoeid from './FindWoeid'

export default class EuropeMap extends Component {

  state = {
    previousCountryStyle: "",
    previousCountryCode: "",
    currentCountryCode: ""
  }

  handleAllClickEvents = evt => {
    var countryCode = evt.target.id;
    console.log(countryCode);

      if (this.state.previousCountryStyle == "") {
        this.setState({previousCountryCode: countryCode, currentCountryCode: countryCode})
        evt.target.style.fill = '#ff0000';
      } else {
        FindWoeid();
        this.setState({previousCountryCode: countryCode, currentCountryCode: countryCode});
        this.setPreviousCountryToGrey(this.state.previousCountryStyle);
        evt.target.style.fill = "#ff0000";
      }
      this.setState({previousCountryStyle: evt.target.style})
    };
    setPreviousCountryToGrey = (st) => {
      st.fill = "#c0c0c0";
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleAllClickEvents}>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          version="1"
          width="900"
          height="700"
          viewBox="1754 161 9938 7945"
          id="svg2">
          <defs id="defs8" fill="none">
            <linearGradient id="linearGradient5669">
              <stop id="stop5671" offset="0" stopColor="silver" />
            </linearGradient>
            <clipPath id="clipPath7195">
              <rect
                width="7331.494"
                height="6873.128"
                x="1594.606"
                y="163.352"
                id="rect7197"
                fill="green"
                stroke="#fff"
                strokeWidth="2.352"
              />
            </clipPath>
          </defs>
          <rect
            width="12386.153"
            height="7934.971"
            x="-340.658"
            y="162.747"
            id="ocean"
            fill="none"
            strokeWidth="6.112"
          />
```

Comment: So where is this component, is it a child of this component?.   Is this component a child of that component,.  If it's neither, it's a little tricky as you have no means of passing state.  This is were having a better state management system in place come in, eg. Redux is a popular choice here.

Comment: Is the other component a child of this component?

Comment: What other component? The "best" way to do it depends on how your app is actually structured (and if you're using any other state mgmt lib, e.g., Redux). If they're both contained in a parent component then it might make sense to set the country code on that parent (via a callback property) and pass it as a prop to the relevant children.

Comment: Where is the state being used in the view?

Comment: To be honest, I struggle to learn react basics and structuring, as it is hard for me to adapt outside my normal routines. 
But this component is the only component that has state currently. And the other component I have, that should retrieve WOEID's given Country Codes, should be a child component for this one, as they should work together.

Comment: When loading the app, you see the europe map on the start-page. When clicking on e.g Poland, I want to list cities in Poland, by fetching from a external API using the WOEID for poland.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this depending on how your files are structured and how deep your understanding of React is.  The simplest way to solve your problem is to pass props directly from a parent component to a child component.
You can do this using the below code in your parent component.

```
render() {
    return <ChildComponent countryCode={this.state.currentCountryCode} />;
  }
```

The child component will now have access to `this.props.countryCode`

Comment: I get an error when trying to insert
    <FindWoeid countryCode={this.state.currentCountryCode}/>
in my render() method.

Comment: Could you show us what your code looks like and what the error looks like?

Comment: You can download the code via. GitHub link if you want? Not sure I have much more code to show regarding this problem

Comment: can you show the error message? Also link to github.

Comment: try this github: https://github.com/NikolaiRojahn/WeatherProjectStackOverFlow

The error was an JSX syntax error, about some react fragment when trying to pass the state to the child component.

Comment: I can't find the code that I recommended anywhere? Have you pushed that to github?

Comment: If you clone the project from the above github, you have the whole project. The component file with the code provided here is EuropeMap.js, and the other component I want to parse state to is FindWoeid.js. (Even though the file is almost empty )

Comment: If you havn't seen, the component folder is inside the src folder.

Comment: I saw the components, but I don't think you have implemented my code in the project.  try adding the code  I posted to your EuropeMap component in the render() method.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have another component named after **OtherComponent** that you want to call

**from EuropeMap**.

There are many strategies to do that according the state management tool you are using.

But i guess you are starting with ReactJS so try this simple solution:

```
Props = { 
  previousCountryCode=""  
}

class OtherComponent extends Component<Props> {

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    //return your the other component content
        //access previousCountryCode by doing
        let countryCode = this.props.previousCountryCode;
  }

}
export default OtherComponent;
```

Then in your component your first have to import the OtherComponent like this:

```
import {OtherComponent} from 'path/to/OtherComponent.js'
```

then you can pass the country code as an attribute to that component by calling it like this in the return statement of the **EuropeMap** render method:

```
<OtherComponent previousCountryCode={this.state.previousCountryCode} />
```